# OCI architect associate autoscaling question

Tags: cloud, autoscaling, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZjv6.png)

Various references indicate that the correct answer is the one referring to the CPU. Can someone corroborate and explain the answer to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer should be creating scaling policy for CPU. Generally, If your system is ram starved, yes it can cause problems, as your system will start going to the hard drive for more memory, from the pagefile. But RAM doesn't necessarily slow down your computer when it appears to be running low. When you have a bunch of programs open, your computer's running slowly, and your RAM is maxed out, you're experiencing the bad side of high memory usage. Generally the Memory consumption within 70%-80% is considered good utilization but on the other hand High CPU utilization slows down the system.